# Embed RSS into HTML

Tags: html, rss, embed

I would like to embed an RSS feed from a site of mine into another site. Is there any free service that can do this for me or a way I can insert the HTML or javaScript?

Comment: You would need to consume the RSS, transform it into HTML, then paste it into another page. It would be static in the resulting page...defeating the entire purpose of RSS. And you'd have to do the entire process over again every time you posted something new in the RSS feed.

Comment: Any possible way in javaScript?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript will not be able to load an RSS feed from a different domain; a page on domain A is not allowed to make a simple GET request to domain B because of security restrictions.  However, if you build a proxy under the same domain using your server-side language of choice, your JavaScript can load the content from there.  Here's a really simplified example using jQuery on the client and ASP.NET on the server.

Client:

```
$.get('Proxy.ashx?feed=http://stackoverflow.com/feeds', function(data) {
    // Do something with the feed
});
```

Server:

```
public class Proxy : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            context.Response.Write(
                webClient.DownloadString(context.Request.QueryString["feed"]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the link to the current page's RSS like so:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="link_here">
```

But to have it visible in a web page, you'll need to use at least a server side script if no JavaScript is used. It's not available in plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use jQuery to pull the RSS (its an XML Format) with a `$.ajax('http://pathToRssFeed')` and then format it and put it into the page using something like [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/). It's very simple.